# Error while installinng libimobiledevice in ubuntu 14.04

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, electron, libimobiledevice

After installing libimobiledevice in ubuntu 14.04, when I run command 'ideviceinfo' it is generating error

'Could not connect to lockdownd, error "code -5"'

I have other dependencies - build-essential
libudev-dev,
libimobiledevice6,
libimobiledevice-utils,
libusb-1.0-0-dev,
libimobiledevice-dev,
libzip-dev

Correctly installed with no error.
Can I get some advices about the error ?

Answer (score 1):

You didn't mention how you acquired libimobiledevice - did you install it via apt-get or did you compile it from source?

Ubuntu 14.04 ships with a very old version of libimobiledevice, and there have been changes made to libimobiledevice to provide compatibility with newer versions of iOS which are probably not in Ubuntu 14.04.

We host a PPA which provides up-to-date builds of libimobiledevice; currently only for Ubuntu 16.04 though. You can find it at https://launchpad.net/~quamotion/+archive/ubuntu/ppa/+packages .

Let me know if you need help configuring the PPA and installing the latest libimobiledevice.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I have resolved the problem. The problem was with ubuntu 14.04 as you have said. It worked fine in Ubuntu 16.04